# Merging two RTF files in Java

Tags: java, rtf

I have two or more rtf files in the form of StringWriter. How can I merge them so that the RTF headers are not doubled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [iTextRTF](http://itextrtf.sourceforge.net/) library. Something along these lines:

```
rtfWriter.importRtfDocument(new FileReader("testfile_in.rtf"));
```

or

```
RtfWriter2 rtfWriter = RtfWriter2.getInstance(
    document, new FileOutputStream("out_file.rtf")
); 
document.open(); 
rtfWriter.importRtfDocument(new FileInputStream("in_file.rtf"), null); 
document.close();
```

Comment: the iText group seems to have stopped maintaining iTextRTF and has switched their focus to PDF only. Furthermore, merging documents with tables is a bit screwy.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use 3rd party libraries, here is an alternative answer that reads from two different RTF files and concatenates them into one:
[How to concatenate 2 RTFs into one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41189071/6297496)

It has fully working code that you could use.