# Can anybody educate me on merging two RTF files into one in java and convert it into readable text?

Tags: java

How do I merge two rtf files into one, and how do i make them a readable text rtf files.  I did the simple FileReader and used a while loop to show one rtf file I am trying to read, but it shows up in a crazy format.

I have never used rtf before and really never heard of it so if anybody can school me or help me on merging two rtf files together into one file or just show me how I can display what I just read using FileReader, into readable text.

Thank you

Comment: Merge two files? This could mean a lot of things. Your question is currently too broad

Comment: I need to make for example file1.rtf and file2.rtf into file3.rtf.  Where file1 an file2 exist and file3 does not.

Comment: Imo this is a valid question. The op wants to concatenate two RTF files into one using Java. OP you could use Java Swing's RTF editor (or Apache Tika) to read both files as plain text, then concatenate the contents and save to a third file. You can look up on google for examples of that.

Comment: If they say _concatenation_ or _append file2 to file1_, then I think it's valid **as long as** they've got code to show what they've attempted.

Comment: I tried, and I am lost and have no other guidence.  can you please help me and give me some hints and clues on what to google.  I googled but either I have no clue on the topic or just lost.

Comment: where could i find a tutorial for beginners on this matter.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenating two RTF files isn't as straightforward as directly appending one file to another. RTF files have header information with metadata such as styles, character encoding, etc. which can be in conflict.

Having said that, there are certain workarounds and libraries that allow you to do hack your way through this mess - to a certain extent. You could:

1. You could use Java Swing's [RTFEditorKit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/rtf/RTFEditorKit.html) to extract text from both the files, concatenate them, and save to a new file.
2. Use a third party library like [this](http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html)

There are other libraries too like Apache Tika, POI(if you convert your RTFs to MS Word formats first) that enable you to do more or less the same thing with varying degrees of quality and efficiency.

I hope this will help you as a starting point in this effort. Once you start following a particular approach and if you face issues, you can post specific questions about that on stackoverflow later along with what you have done till that point.

*EDIT*

Since I had some free time today, I actually went ahead and did the actual implementation for concatenating two RTF files. I have tested the code and it is working as expected for two similarly formatted RTF files.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.Element;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFEditorKit;

public class RTFReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File input1 = new File("C:\\ragu\\input1.rtf");
    File input2 = new File("C:\\ragu\\input2.rtf");
    File output = new File ("C:\\ragu\\output.rtf");

    FileInputStream fis1 = null;
    FileInputStream fis2 = null;
    FileOutputStream fw = null;
    try {
        fis1 = new FileInputStream(input1);
        fis2 = new FileInputStream(input2);
        fw = new FileOutputStream(output);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        Document doc1 = load(fis1);
        Document doc2 = load(fis2);
        //String contents1 = doc1.getText(0, doc1.getLength());
        //String contents2 = doc2.getText(0, doc2.getLength());
        mergeDocument((DefaultStyledDocument)doc2, (DefaultStyledDocument)doc1);
        RTFEditorKit rtf = new RTFEditorKit();
        rtf.write(fw, doc1, 0, doc1.getLength());
        //System.out.println(contents1+contents2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            fis1.close();
            fis2.close();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static Document load(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    RTFEditorKit rtf = new RTFEditorKit();
    Document doc = rtf.createDefaultDocument();
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    try {
        rtf.read(input, doc, 0);
    } catch (BadLocationException ble) {
        throw new IOException(ble);
    }
    return doc;
}

public static void mergeDocument(DefaultStyledDocument source, DefaultStyledDocument dest) throws BadLocationException {
    ArrayList<DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec> specs=new ArrayList<DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec>();
    DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec spec=new DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec(new SimpleAttributeSet(), 
             DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec.EndTagType);
    specs.add(spec);
    fillSpecs(source.getDefaultRootElement(), specs, false);
    spec=new DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec(new SimpleAttributeSet(), DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec.StartTagType);
    specs.add(spec);

    DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec[] arr = new DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec[specs.size()];
    specs.toArray(arr);
    insertSpecs(dest, dest.getLength(), arr);
}

protected static void insertSpecs(DefaultStyledDocument doc, int offset, DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec[] specs) {
    try {
        Method m=DefaultStyledDocument.class.getDeclaredMethod("insert", new Class[] {int.class, DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec[].class});
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(doc, new Object[] {offset, specs});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

protected static void fillSpecs(Element elem, ArrayList<DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec> specs, boolean includeRoot) throws BadLocationException{
    DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec spec;
    if (elem.isLeaf()) {
        String str=elem.getDocument().getText(elem.getStartOffset(), elem.getEndOffset()-elem.getStartOffset());
        spec=new DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec(elem.getAttributes(), 
                 DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec.ContentType,str.toCharArray(), 0, str.length());
        specs.add(spec);
    }
    else {
        if (includeRoot) {
            spec=new DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec(elem.getAttributes(), DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec.StartTagType);
            specs.add(spec);
        }
        for (int i=0; i<elem.getElementCount(); i++) {
            fillSpecs(elem.getElement(i), specs, true);
        }

        if (includeRoot) {
            spec=new DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec(elem.getAttributes(), DefaultStyledDocument.ElementSpec.EndTagType);
            specs.add(spec);
        }
    }
}

}
```

OP: Keep in mind that you cannot expect complete implementations henceforth on SO. I just did it because I had some free time, but usually you would start doing something on your own. Enjoy!

*EDIT2* Forgot to mention credits:
The major lifting work is done by the code I picked up from [here](http://java-sl.com/tip_merge_documents.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am an entry level java developer, and am totally new to this.  Career change and fresh out of school, and the guy who I work with does not want to help me at all.  Googling now, but still just way lost on this rtf file thing.

Comment: Don't worry dude, we've all been there at some point. I guess the reason the other guy doesn't wanna help you is because this isn't very straightforward, and he himself might not be able to do it correctly. Have patience, start researching, eventually you'll get something that works. Good luck!
PS: If you are OK with this answer, can you mark it as accepted? like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Is there a way you can direct me to get me started.  I have no clue what so ever.  thanks

Comment: @user2852918 I edited my answer. Now you have the complete working code which you can use. Hope this helps!

Comment: Chetan Jadhav CD,  THANK YOU!!!  I have to review the code to wrap my head around it.  There was no way I could of got this on my own.  I owe you big, for showing and teaching me.

Comment: @user2852918 You're welcome bro :) Lemme know if you have any questions